# How the Script activity output be pushed in form csv /structured format as a sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

If i run the script activity ,it will give an output in json , how to push that data in csv /anyother format to blob/database ???

Consider i have 1 million rows outputed from Script activity(Single Query) ??

Comment: Instead of using script activity, try using copy activity and give the same query in Source settings and copy that into BLOB / SQL db

Comment: What are you trying to attempt with script activity?

Comment: Simple Select * from and a group by .

Comment: It can be done through Copy activity but am asking can we do the same with Script activity ?

Comment: You can copy the data to new table in SQL by writing the script like this. `select * into new_table from ( --Query--)a`

Comment: If Target table is already created in Database, then try giving the script as , `Insert into new_table --Select Query--`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the json output of script actvity and copy it to SQL database. Below is the approach.

- In Script actvity,  Query is given in script settings.
  `select * from sampletb`

[image]

**Output of the script activity: **

[image]

- Then Output of this activity is stored in a variable of string type.
  `@string(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows)`

[image]

- In SQL database, target table named `test_tgt` is created.
- Another script activity is taken and below script is written to copy to SQL database.

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(4000)=N'@{variables('v1')}';
INSERT INTO test_tgt
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
Col varchar(60) ,
col1 varchar(50)
);
```

[image]

Comment: If my input load is like 10gb Table ,can it load womith same code ???

Comment: I could not repro with large files. I think this should work for large files also. Otherwise try using Copy activity by giving query in source settings.

Comment: am checking if it works for large files , does set variable limit is defined , is sufficient to store crores of rows in json ???

Comment: There is no limit defined in variable